# SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "SP" on cross-origin object

Tags: sharepoint

Running Sharepoint 2016 Custom Addin and getting the following error on boot...

SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "SP" on cross-origin object

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide read access to your app(from Visual Studio).

And just some kb for your reference：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library

[cross domain issue when accessing sharepoint list from sharepoint app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766875/cross-domain-issue-when-accessing-sharepoint-list-from-sharepoint-app)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/12/12/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps/